# Nest.js is giving cors error even when cors is enabled

Tags: typescript, cors, nestjs

I am developing a next.js application with nest.js as the backend. Now, I am having cors error even when I have cors enabled in my `main.ts` file of nest.js.

Here's my main.ts file.

```
    import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
    import { AppModule } from './app.module';
    import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';
    
    async function bootstrap() {
      const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
      if (process.env.APP_ENV !== 'production') {
        app.enableCors({
          allowedHeaders: '*',
          origin: '*',
          credentials: true,
        });
      } else {
        app.enableCors({
          origin: process.env.FE_URL,
          credentials: true,
        });
      }
    
      app.use(cookieParser());
      await app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000);
    }
    bootstrap();
```

I also tried the following.

```
    import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
    import { AppModule } from './app.module';
    import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';
    
    async function bootstrap() {
      const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
      
      app.enableCors({
        allowedHeaders: '*',
        origin: '*',
        credentials: true,
      });
    
      app.use(cookieParser());
      await app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000);
    }
    bootstrap();
```

I also tried this

```
    app.enableCors({
      origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
      credentials: true,
    });
```

Now, from the frontend in `_app.js`, I am defining Axios global config like the following.

```
    axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://localhost:5000';
    axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```

Then in my `login.tsx` file, I am sending the request to the nest.js application like the following.

```
    const {data } = await axios.post('/auth/login', values);
```

Here's values is an object that has a username and password.

Here is the error.

[image: Cors Error]

[image: Cors Error Description]

I also tried every other solution from other StackOverflow questions. But none of them solved my problem. It actually worked a few days ago. I don't know what happened.

What am I doing wrong here? It's been driving me bananas now. If you need, I can provide more code.

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#credentialed_requests_and_wildcards

Comment: @jub0bs I also tried writing it like `origin: http://localhost:3000`. It still didn't work.

Comment: You're using the wildcard (`*`), not just for the origin, but also for the headers. As explained in the MDN Web Docs I linked to above, that won't work in conjunction with credentialed requests. Instead, try `allowedHeaders: ['content-type']`.

Comment: What is the actual error message? There are different types of CORS errors.

Comment: @derpirscher see the screenshots.

Comment: I don't see a error message there. Just the screenshot of the network tab which says "CORS error". Have a look in the console output, there will be a more detailed error message

Comment: @derpirscher my cors errors are gone. But now I am getting a 404 not found error even though `auth/login` exists in my auth controller

Comment: maybe in the frontend  you  putted 'localhost ' insead of  'http : // localhost'

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As explained on the [MDN Web Docs about CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#credentialed_requests_and_wildcards), you cannot use the wildcard (`*`), whether it be to allow an origin or request headers (or request methods), in conjunction with credentialed requests. A more authoritative (though perhaps more dry) resource is the [Fetch standard](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#http-new-header-syntax):

> For `Access-Control-Expose-Headers`, `Access-Control-Allow-Methods`, and `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` response headers, the value `*` counts as a wildcard for requests without credentials. For such requests there is no way to solely match a header name or method that is `*`.

Accordingly, the following code produces a dysfunctional CORS middleware; [you could argue that your CORS middleware library should prevent its users from producing such a dysfunctional CORS middleware](https://jub0bs.com/posts/2023-02-08-fearless-cors/#6-treat-cors-as-a-compilation-target), but it sadly does not.

```js
app.enableCors({
  allowedHeaders: '*',
  origin: '*',
  credentials: true,
});
```

Instead, you should eschew the wildcard altogether and explicitly specify the allowed origin and allowed request headers, like so:

```js
app.enableCors({
  allowedHeaders: ['content-type'],
  origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
  credentials: true,
});
```

Comment: Cors error solved. But now I am getting a 404 not found error which is even weirder considering it worked a few days ago

Comment: @Pranta I don't expect the 404 to be related to your earlier CORS issue. You should probably ask a separate question about it, if cannot find a solution by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Found this better expressive and work nice

```
const whitelist = [
      'http://localhost:3000',
      'http://localhost:3001',
      'http://localhost:3002',
      'http://localhost:8000',
      'http://127.0.0.1:3000',
      'http://127.0.0.1:3001',
      'http://127.0.0.1:3002',
      'http://10.0.2.2:3000',
    ];

const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, {
    logger,
    cors: {
      methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE', 'OPTIONS', 'HEAD'],
      origin: function (origin, callback) {
        if (!origin) {
          callback(null, true);
          return;
        }
        if (
          whitelist.includes(origin) || // Checks your whitelist
          !!origin.match(/yourdomain\.com$/) // Overall check for your domain
        ) {
          console.log('allowed cors for:', origin);
          callback(null, true);
        } else {
          console.log('blocked cors for:', origin);
          callback(new ImATeapotException('Not allowed by CORS'), false);
        }
      },
    },
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I needed pass `content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` in Request Header using axios.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed it for my case.

```
const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, {
    bodyParser: true,
  });


  app.enableCors({
    "origin": "*",
    "methods": "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",
    "preflightContinue": false,
    "optionsSuccessStatus": 204
  });
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case I followed the [official docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/security/cors) which says following to enable CORS on nestjs

```
const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
app.enableCors();
await app.listen(3000);
```

but I still got the CORS error because of a CORS plugin which I installed long time ago.

So I switched off "Allow CORS" plugin in my browser and the error is gone. (If you have any similar plugin turn it off and see if it's working for you.)

Comment: if you not finding this answer helpful mention why here OR mention your issue with my answer here so that i can improve my answer!

Comment: you are suggesting only to do the basic cors and the questions say they already do that, and switched off "Allow CORS" don't solve the problem, other person that use the app and don't have that in the browser will have the problem of the cors

Answer (score -1):

This solution in my case that similar, I enable cors in the nest.js to fetch data in my react application.

In your nest application do this:

first step:
install: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors-ts

```
npm i cors-ts
```

second step:

```
import cors from 'cors-ts'
```

and paste this:

```
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: '#front-end-url',
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
  })
)
```

into your file main.ts and then restart your applications.