# Nest.js/Angular - CORS Enabled but still getting a CORS error while making requests

Tags: angular, angularjs, cors, nestjs

I am building a little calculator app to learn Nest.js and Angular. I have set up a server hosting a simple web API with a few endpoints, one of which returns a list of all the currently supported Opcodes on the backend. I am trying to fetch (on init) and consume this list to populate a dropdown selector on the frontend.

##### Frontend

`calculator-app/src/app/calculator-form/` holds the form component that consumes the request. All it is doing is calling `OpcodeService.getSupportedOpcodes()` and logging the result. At this point, I know I'll need to do more work with the result object, but because of the CORS error I haven't gotten that far.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { OpcodeService } from '../services/opcode.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-calculator-form',
  templateUrl: './calculator-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./calculator-form.component.scss'],
  providers: [ OpcodeService ]
})
export class CalculatorFormComponent {
  supportedOpcodes: string[] = ['?']

  constructor(private opcodeService: OpcodeService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.opcodeService.getListOfSupportedOpcodes().subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res);
    })
  }
}
```

`calculator-app/src/app/services/opcode.service.ts` makes the actual HTTP request. This endpoint works as expected when I test with Postman, and I did my best to emulate the header that worked with postman. This is also fairly simple, but its possible I'm missing some configuration here.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Enviornment } from '../enviornment';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  // declares that this service should be created
  // by the root application injector.
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class OpcodeService {
  supportedOpcodes: string[] = [];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getListOfSupportedOpcodes() {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders()
      .set('content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
      .set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    
    return this.http.get(Enviornment.serverUrl + "/opcode", {'headers':  headers});
  }
}
```

##### Backend

I'm reasonably confident there is nothing wrong with my routing. As mentioned above I was able to see the values returning as expected from GET -> localhost:3000/opcode. So here is my `main.ts` file, with the `enableCors()` configuration object.

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.enableCors({
    allowedHeaders: ['content-type'],
    origin: 'http://localhost:4200/'
  });
  await app.listen(3000);
}

bootstrap().then(function() {
  console.log("\nReady for maths!");
});
```

[Screen capture of CORS error in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhtHW.png)

I have tried enabling CORS with the allowed headers. I know that Nest.js has issues parsing `form-data` by default, so I tried setting the headers of the `GET` request. Tried setting the origin following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70609616/nest-js-is-giving-cors-error-even-when-cors-is-enabled).

[Here is the full repository. Feel free to open issues with any other feedback!](https://github.com/nathan-moore-97/NestJsCalculator)

Comment: Providing the CORS error would be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access it from the front end locally you will have to change the main.ts enabled CORS settings.

From

```
app.enableCors({
  allowedHeaders: ['content-type'],
  origin: 'http://localhost:4200/'
});
```

To

```
app.enableCors(); //without any configuration option.
```

Main.ts

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

async function bootstrap() {
 const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
 app.enableCors();
 await app.listen(3000);
}

 bootstrap().then(function() {
 console.log("\nReady for maths!");
});
```

To handle it properly, we can keep this setting base on the environments settings to make this production usable code. The CORS setting can be kept in the application configuration on the hosting could service as well.

```
if (process.env.ENV === 'development' && process.env.LOCAL_ENV === 
'enabled') {
  app.enableCors();
 }
```

Working request from the angular app localhost: http://localhost:4200

[Working request from the angular app local host](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQ8ZP.png)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the URL that you're trying to hit has `http://` or `https://` at the begining.

Answer (score 0):

I'll also add here that the extra headers in `opcode.service.ts` are not necessary. This explanation and analogy was given by Omar on my GitHub. I'll be making the repository private again, so I'll paste it here as well:

##### Answer

The headers Access-Control-Allow-Origin and allow-origins should be configured on the server side, not the client side.

Imagine that you are a bouncer at a bar and you have a policy that only allows entry to people from a specific address. Now, picture a scenario where a customer approaches the bar and asks you to let them in. They show you their identification (the handshake headers), which includes a note requesting entry (this note represents the client-supplied headers that were in that method). However, as the bouncer, you understand that it is ultimately the bar's decision to determine who gets to enter, not the customer's

I recommend you that if you need to use headers for every single call that you're making, look for an `Interceptor`, if not, the simpler the better.

If you need to send a x-www-form-urlencoded call, you can send a FormData object if needed. Like this:

```
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('parameter', 'value');
return this.http.post(URL, formData);
```